# There is a way to import database files(.MYD .MYI) in mysql8?

Tags: mysql

In mysql5.7 I can copy whole folder of a database when I want to backup it.
I mistook can do this in Mysql8.0.So I didn't do anyting when I reinstall the system.

Now I use "show databased":

```
mysql> show databases \g
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| blog               |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It didn't display old database "blog2" but blog2 folder is there.
[here is screenshot my disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlFih.png)